# PHP OOP - Including required files properly

Tags: php, oop

Coming from a strong background in ActionScript 3, the process of requiring/importing a class that will be referenced / used / extended in another class is as follows:

```
import package.inner.ClassName;
```

This is required at the top of every external class file that will make use of `ClassName`, meaning it's required if I do any of the following, for example:

- `public class NewClass extends ClassName`
- `var someVar:ClassName = new ClassName();`
- `function someMethod():ClassName{ .. }`

etc

I've got a fair bit of knowledge with PHP, ie I know how to use it to work with MySQL, output text, write functions, set up some basic classes, etc.

I've always just had one main class for small websites, which I create an instance of on the web-page at the top and work with from there, eg:

```
<?php
    class Website
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            // connect to mysql, etc
        }

        public function example()
        {
            echo "example text";
        }
    }
?>
```

And then:

```
<?php
    require "whatever/class.website.php";
    $website = new Website();
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $website->example();
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is fine, but now I want to start moving onto some larger projects with multiple classes. At first I was going OK, but after trying to set up a base class for multiple classes, I've run into a problem:

As an example, I've set up the following base class:

```
class Base
{
    public function test($input)
    {
        echo $input;
    }
}
```

From there I set up a class that extends this:

```
require "class.base.php";

class ExampleOne extends Base
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->test("example one");
    }
}
```

And then checked to see if all worked as expected, which it did:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php
            require "class.exampleone.php";

            $one = new ExampleOne();
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

I then went on to create an additional class that extends `Base`, which is where I ran into problems..

```
require "class.base.php";

class ExampleTwo extends Base
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->test("example two");
    }
}
```

When I tried to create an instance of this class, or even just use `require` to gain access to the class, I get an error:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Base in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\class.base.php on line 3

So admittedly this error is pretty self explanatory, it's because I've used `require "class.base.php";` at the top of each class - which is what you would do in ActionScript 3 because I'm making use of the base class (extending it).

I guess I'm just finding it hard to understand how I should be doing this. Where should I be putting my `require` for `Base`? It seems strange to omit it in the latter class I've extended, because if I don't make an instance of my first class then the base class won't be included at all.

Any advice would be awesome!

Comment: You must learn and use autoload - http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read about how [spl_autoload_register](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) works. It would solve your issue in a bit more reusable manner.

Additionally, you should stop doing "work" in the `__construct` method. Use it only for assignment. And if your `Website` class requires a db connection, then you should create a PDO ( or mysqli ? ) object, and pass it to the instance in the constructor.

P.S. watching ["Clean Code Talks - Unit Testing"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEhu57pih5w) and actually other lectures from the series would be strongly recommended.

Comment: Thanks for the link in your final point, it's been pretty eye-opening.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `require_once()` statement.  It functions just like the require statement, but will check to make sure that the base class hasn't been included yet and will load it if needed.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php

You may also want to look into web frameworks depending on the size of your website, but that's outside of the question scope :)

Comment: Thanks for this, can you help me out with the question I asked via comment on the other answer?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `require_once` instead of `require`. That way PHP will only include the file if it has not already done so.

Comment: That works, but is using `require_once()` at the top of all my extending classes the most conventional way to go about this, or should I be doing something completely different?

Comment: You should be doing something different. First of all - use autoloader -> http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: The autoloader usually gets benchmarked slower than `require_once`... And if I'm not mistaken not available pre-php5 correct?  Why would you prefer the autoloader?

Comment: @JackWink, "i'm not using php5" was an excuse like 5 years ago. Today it's a failure. And if you really are this picky about execution time, then you shouldn't suggest frameworks in your answer :p

Comment: @egis, I'm sorry, I was genuinely asking why you would prefer the autoloader.  Unfortunately, I do have to support PHP 4 more often than I'd like.

Comment: @JackWink, well then in your case yes, you should use require/_once (if you have to support php4). In all other cases I'd choose autoloader instead of tens or even hundreds of require statements. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`require_once`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to hack your problem above use `require_once`.

But just like egis said, an autoloader is much better because it includes your classes on the fly as needed. Saves you from manually including classes in a lot of places. What if your class depended on so many other classes?

Here's [a tutorial on how to do that](http://anthonybush.com/projects/autoloader/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to not even have to care, you should use [__autoload](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) and let php do all the heavy lifting for you.